# KVM - How can I see what kind of preallocation uses a qcow2 file?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

How can I see what kind of preallocation uses a qcow2 file?
I tried with the command qemu-img info filename.qcow2 but the type of pre-allocation (off; full; metadata; falloc; etc) is not shown. Thank you.